# Python liburl2 timeout; can ping server fine, and wget works fine;

Tags: python, web-services, api, dreamhost

I'm trying to use Python's liburl2 to access the Dreamhost API documented here: http://wiki.dreamhost.com/API

Here is my code:

```
request  = urllib2.Request('https://api.dreamhost.com/?key=<key>')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
page = response.read()
print(page)
```

This invariably fails with the error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

I'm absolutely stumped, because I can ping api.dreamhost.com just fine, and wget  https://api.dreamhost.com/?key= works fine, too.

Any ideas?

Comment: With the example code above, it works for me.  I get an error message about requiring a command.

Comment: Your example works fine here. Are you behind a proxy? Also, you might want to generate a new API key after posting yours here.

Comment: FYI: I was able to list all of you dns records and see that I can delete or add new records.  Change your key now... and delete this question.

Comment: It's been deleted.  I'm such an idiot.  8-|  That's what I get for trying to do web development with a cranky 1-year-old crying on my shoulder.  Thanks for the heads' up.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not behind a proxy.  Behind a router.  But I can do wget and ping the host just fine.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that since wget and ping can see the page/host just fine, that it's probably not a firewall/proxy issue?  Or could there still be something set up wrong with the connection on my end (even though wget can see it fine)?

Comment: I'm hitting this same issue with some node.js code that worked fine the last time I used it. I've since moved to a new home with a new internet connection (windstream) and firewall / router (Sagemcom F@st 1740n), so that sounds like a possible culprit. I'll let you know if I figure anything out.

Comment: BTW, when I make the request with `wget`, it fails because the security certificate is invalid. When I retry with ` --no-check-certificate` it works. However, I tried the equivalent option in node.js and it didn't have any affect.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I faced the same problem, and found the solution through two other questions.

This, that shows me the problem is with the handshake using SSLv3:

[OpenSSL issues in Debian Wheezy](https://serverfault.com/a/521926/204752)

And this, that gives some possible solutions:

[Python HTTPS requests (urllib2) to some sites fail on Ubuntu 12.04 without proxy](https://askubuntu.com/a/488277/3987)